# periodic "value too great for base" doing math on date output in bash

Tags: bash, date

```
    ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
1441637184683
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000000))
730
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000))
bash: 088253206: value too great for base (error token is "088253206")
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000))
bash: 085061725: value too great for base (error token is "085061725")
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10000))
59078
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000))
672523
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10))
12079796
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10000))
74644
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/100000))
1403
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000000))
5
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/100000))
9977
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000000))
360
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/100000))
6663
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10))
10325856
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/100))
8020128
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/1000))
9461
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10000))
81272
ubu@bruntu:/home/wideDB1$ echo $(($(date +%N)/10000))
bash: 046340492: value too great for base (error token is "046340492")
```

I must use this function in a bash script accurately for synchronizing milliseconds between tasks but here is very unstable. Anyone can help me to figure out what best solution for this work?

Cheers!
Alessandro

Comment: You get 'value too great' errors because the leading zero indicates an octal number for the shell when doing arithmetic. You can remove it by sed -E 's/^0//'.

Comment: See also http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/august

Comment: @user1666959, boo hiss re: suggesting calling an external tool for something the shell can do built-in.

Answer (score 2):

A string of digits beginning with 0 is treated as an octal number by default; you just need to tell `bash` to treat the string captured from `date +%N` as a decimal number in all cases, by prefix it with `10#`.

```
$ echo $(( 10#$(date +%N)/1000000))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it seems working good! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Digit strings inside of `$((...))` are interpreted as numbers, but numbers starting with `0` are interpreted as **octal** numbers, i.e. in base 8.

You can easily remove the leading zeroes by parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob          # Enable extended globbing -- in this case, +(0)

for i in {1..20} ; do
    nanos=$(date +%N)
    echo -n "$nanos -> "
    nanos=${nanos##+(0)}  # Remove as many 0's from the left as possible.
    echo $nanos
done
```